# Type '"var(--header-position)"' is not assignable to type 'Position | undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, types, css-variables

### Description of Problem

I'm trying to use A CSS Custom property to style a component in a nextjs application using TypeScript. Every other CSS property accepts the CSS variables except for the position property which returns the following error:

`Type '"var(--header-position)"' is not assignable to type 'Position | undefined'`

Some more context. I'm also using tailwind, but I don't think that's affecting anything. I'm also generating the properties using the setProperty() method.

### Example codeblock

```ts
function Header() {
  return (
    <>
      <Container
        className="top-0 order-last -mb-3 pt-3"
        style={{ position: 'var(--header-position)' }}
      >
        <div
          className="top-[var(--avatar-top,theme(spacing.3))] w-full"
          style={{ position: 'var(--header-inner-position)' }}
        >
         ...
        </div>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

### What I've Tried

I've tried searching for a similar propblem but most of the time people seem to be setting the custom property using a stylesheet. However, I'm setting the custom property using setProperty() based on scroll events and window resizing. But again all the other properties are working without throughing compilation errors.

Comment: Does it work at runtime?

Comment: @vr. Yes it works fine. The elements have the position property with the correct value.

Comment: My inclination would be to assert it then: https://tsplay.dev/w1E3Kw, even if it's inherently unsafe, I don't think it does any harm here.

Comment: Thank you for that. Even though it's unsafe it's good enough for me, as the app is building now at least!

Comment: I have this exact same issue, and thought I could fix it with 'use client' at the top, but no dice. It "works" for development, but fails production build

Answer (score 0):

Assigin `React.CSSProperties` interface  fixed problem for me.

**Example:**

```
style={{ position: 'var(--header-inner-position)' }: React.CSSProperties}
```